# Take data from a static label and use it to populate tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an application that has multiple views, taking data from one view and storing it in a table in another. I have labels that are updated with data when a calculate button and a button that is hopefully going to store the data from those labels on their own cell in the UITable in another cell. I'm currently lost on how I would set up my UITable to create a new cell and pass the data to that cell every time the validate button is pressed.

Comment: there is no `UITable` just `UITableview`

Comment: That's what I meant. There's a [UITableView] on a separate view controller.

Comment: UITableviewDatasource methods and a data populating array ,add the value to the datasource array then `[table reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

This is basic MVC behavior. Table cells are loaded at display time in the UITableView datasource delegate methods. The data should be loaded from some type of store, in your case most likely an array.

When you want to update the data (from anywhere), simply update the data store (array).

Reload the UITableView at will with the `reloadData` method (or whenever the view appears).

Comment: So create multiple cells that each contain its own individual information should I create a class, and then add each class object to the array so each cell basically contains an object?

Comment: @NarimonKardani, that would be a great way to do it. An array of NSDictionary objects (name/value pairs) is also easy to work with. The array needs to have a strong reference and be available from both view controllers. You could pass the array from one controller to the next via `prepareForSegue`, or the array could be in a class outside both view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is that you want to store your UILabels' text values in UITableViewCells on the press of a button?

If this is the case, I would store each text value as an element in an NSArray after every time your button is clicked, like so:

```
// Given:
// 1.) Your labels are IBOutlets
// 2.) Your labels follow the naming convention label1, label2, label3, etc
// 3.) You have an initialized class variable NSMutableArray *labels
// 4.) NUM_OF_LABELS_IN_VIEW is the number of UILabels in your view
// 5.) myTableView is an outlet to your UITableView, and its delegate and datasource are set to your view controller

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    self.labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_OF_LABELS_IN_VIEW; i++){
         [labels addObject:[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"label%i", i]].text ];
    }

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

And your data source methods should look something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.labels count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = self.labels[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

If the UITableView is in a separate view controller, just assign the `NSArray *labels` to a @property on the presenting view controller.

Comment: I'm trying to set it up but it's just not having it. Could I post the xcode project so you could take a look?

Comment: Sure, upload it to a file sharing website and I'll take a look.

Comment: Heh that's only the xcode project, gonna need to take a look at all the files, like the view controllers and stuff

Comment: They should all be in the folder?